# Option in method call not compiling

Tags: scala

In order to get height of a binary tree I use this code :

```
object optionfun {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  case class Node(var isVisited: Boolean, var leftNode: Option[Node], var rightNode: Option[Node], name: String) {
    def this(name: String) = this(false, None, None, name)
  }

  val a = new Node("a")
  val b = new Node("b")
  val c = new Node("c")
  a.leftNode = Some(b)
  a.rightNode = Some(c)

  def getHeight(root: Option[Node]): Int = {

    //if root contains a None type then it should return 0, should I pattern match on the option type here?
    Math.max(getHeight(root.leftNode),
      getHeight(root.rightNode.get)) + 1
  }

    getHeight(a)
}
```

But I receive compiler error for line :

```
Math.max(getHeight(root.leftNode)
```

error is :

```
Multiple markers at this line - value leftNode is not a member of Option[optionfun.Node] - value 
 leftNode is not a member of Option[Node]
```

I've mixed up the types somehow but I don't know what to pass into getHeight method "root.leftNode" is of type Option ?

Comment: What should `getHeight` return if `root` is `None`?

Comment: @m-z it should return 0, ill update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with accepting `root` as an `Option[Node]` is that you can't just call `root.leftNode`, you have to `map` or `match` the `Option`.

You could re-write it without the `Option` like this:

```
def getHeight(root: Node): Int = {
    Math.max(
        root.leftNode.map(getHeight(_)).getOrElse(0),
        root.rightNode.map(getHeight(_)).getOrElse(0)
    ) + 1
}
```

Or with `Option`:

```
def getHeight(root: Option[Node]): Int = root match {
   case Some(r) => Math.max(getHeight(r.leftNode), getHeight(r.rightNode)) + 1
   case None => 0
}
```